# Spring security Basic Auth and Form login for the same API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to access all my API's via two authentication mechanisms, Basic Auth & Form login. I know that there are existing questions, but, the answers did not work for me, and my use case is a little bit different.

My config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SecurityConfigBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        final private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public SecurityConfigBasicAuth(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                       @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
            this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
            this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

        // @Bean authenticationProvider()

        // @Bean passwordEncoder()

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().disable()
                    .logout().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfigFormLogin extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        final private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        final private RestfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler restfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
        final private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        public SecurityConfigFormLogin(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                       RestfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler restfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler,
                                       CustomAuthenticationProvider hashAuthenticationProvider) {
            this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
            this.restfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler = restfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
            this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("id1")
                    .passwordParameter("Id2")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/test/login")
                    .successHandler(restfulSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(myFailureHandler())
                    .and()
                    .logout();
        }

        // @Bean myFailureHandler()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I defined two 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters', one for Basic Auth, and one for Form login. The Form login is REST compatible (does not redirect, but gives HTTP responses).

The problem is as follows: The first 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' that is loaded works and overrides the second. The above example, makes it possible to use basic auth, but I cannot login on POST '/test/login', I get a:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1534164906450,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/test/login"
}
```

**Update fixed**: the key was to use the 'requestMatchers()', see answer section for solution (as suggested by jzheaux)

Comment: Nothing good is going to come of configuring two sets of web security filters on the same endpoint. The only thing I can suggest is to use different URLs, one for form login and one for BASIC auth - once authenticated, then you should be able to use the session.

Comment: What am I doing differently from: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples-web.md#sample-multi-http-web-configuration ? other then not defining the url paths.

Comment: And what do you mean by using different URLs? Both authentications, result to specific roles, in which they can access both the same API's

Comment: That's exactly what you are doing differently and exaclty why it doesn't work.

Comment: I specified the url matching, still not working, see update above.

Comment: If you really want two different filter chains, then take a look at http.requestMatchers() first. This will allow you to split your configuration by url fairly cleanly.

The problem you (may) have with your current configuration is that these don't precisely override as much as they merge with one another (if you don't do what I'm recommending above). I'd be curious to try out for myself what the merged configuration of one doing httpBasic and another doing httpBasic().disable would be.

Comment: Lastly, I'm not certain of your usecase, but having separate configs like this usually is only necessary in cases like where they come from different jars and cannot be merged into a single WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Just food for thought.

Comment: I have splitted the filter chain because of different authenticationProviders. The basicAuth uses the UserDetailsService, and the FormLogin uses a custom authentication provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is how I fixed this:

I configured the Basic Auth configuration as:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and();
}
```

If you do not want that the basic authentication returning new cookie with new JSESSIONID, add:

```
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .sessionFixation()
            .migrateSession()
```

The Form login configuration as:

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/test/login")
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("id1")
                    .passwordParameter("id2")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/test/login")
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(myFailureHandler())
                    .and()
                    .logout();
        }
```

Now, it is possible for me to authenticate via the Form login configuration, and use the cookie session id to call /api/** (configured in the Basic Auth configuration). I can also just use the Basic Auth authentication ofcourse.